# How to use recursion to parse text into a tree structure?

Tags: c#, parsing, recursion

I am new to C# and I am completely stuck on a parsing issue where I want to use recursion but my attempts to do so have gotten me nowhere.

I want to read in a file that has the following format:

```
root:
   fileA
   sub1:
      fileB
      fileC
      sub2:
         fileD
         fileE
      fileF
   fileG
   sub3:
      fileH
```

Essentially, the lines ending the colons (:) are supposed to represent directories and the lines that do not end in colons are supposed to represent files in their parent directory as such: **fileA** and **fileG** belong in the *root* directory, **fileB**, **fileC**, and **fileF** are located within the *sub1* directory, and so on (location is determined by indents/spaces).

Thus, I want to read in this file, and more complex files with a similar structure in a better way than I am currently doing it (a horrendous mess of for loops and if statements). I am using simple custom classes for the directories and files (I am not using .NET classes except for StreamReader for reading in the text file line by line)

I have done something similar in python once but for some reason I cannot wrap my head around how to do it in C#, which is silly since this is an abstract problem and the language specific implementations should not matter that much. I guess what does matter is my lack of understanding of how to best apply recursion in situations like these. Am I on the right track? I just sense that there is a much more elegant way of parsing  this file into my self defined classes (retaining a tree structure in the sample text) and I think recursion is the answer. I just cannot see it.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it is less an answer and more a violent shove in the right direction. Or a gentle nudge.

Sample Code in C# trying to use Recursion (incomplete, but I hope it gets across what I am trying to do):

```
public void buildDirectoryFromFile(string file)
{
    string line;
    StreamReader data = new StreamReader(file);           

    int depth = 0;
    while ((line = data.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        depth = line.Length - line.TrimStart(' ').Length;
        parseTextIntoTree(line, depth);
    }            
}  


public void parseTextIntoTree(string line, int depth)
{    
   if (line.Contains(':'))
   {
      //Totally lost      
   }
   else
   {
       //Totally lost
   }         
}
```

Depth in this case refers to the spaces/indents. The more spaces there are between the string and the left margin the 'deeper' it is in the tree.

Comment: Please show us the code that you have already written. Both the c# version and the python if you have it. It makes our job much easier to help you.

Comment: Please show us code for this you have written

Comment: I added some code, I can comment on it more if you life. @Enigmativity

Comment: @SStevens, `root` can be just single?

Comment: @Grundy, I named it that because that is the sample file that I am playing with, but essentially it is just the top of the tree, it can be the top of a subtree, but I used root as a default starting place.

Comment: i mean on first level can be single name, in you sample is _root_? or it can be `_root2_` after all? Also do you select where you save this? i mean class that you want get in result

Comment: @Grundy, If I understand you correctly, the name is not important, it is just the top of a tree/subtree, so yes, it could be anything (root2, top, base, etc). Yeah I can post my classes if you would like but they are just simple Node/Leaf classes that hold the line name as their data (fileG, for example), that part makes sense to me, the parsing does not.

Comment: @SStevens, nope :-) i mean is it possibly more than one _top of a tree/subtree_.

Comment: @Grundy, then let us assume that root is the very top and there is not another top. It is THE top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
public void buildDirectoryFromFile(string file)
{
    string line;
    StreamReader data = new StreamReader(file);           

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    while ((line = data.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lines.Add(line);

    }    
    int lineProcessed = 0;
    ParseTextIntoTree(lines, ref lineProcessed, 0);        
}  

public const int PadCount = 3; // Your padding length in text file

public void ParseTextIntoTree(List<string> lineList, ref int lineProcessed, int depth)
{
    while(lineProcessed < lineList.Count)
    {
        string line = lineList[lineProcessed++];
        int lineDepth = line.Length - line.TrimStart(' ').Length;

        if(lineDepth < depth)
        {
            // If the current depth is lower than the desired depth
            // end of directory structure is reached. Do backtrack
            // and reprocess the line in upper depth
            lineProcessed--;
            return;
        }

        if(line.EndsWith(":"))
        {
            // Do something, perhaps create directory?
            ParseTextIntoTree(lineList, ref lineProcessed, depth + PadCount);
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something, perhaps create file?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I am playing with it as we speak. Thank you. I will respond asap once I understand and implement this.

Comment: I added in the reference to my Directory class and my FileLeaf class and this works. Thank you for the clear code, this helps me understand the concept very well.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have much experience with parsing layout-style or whitespace sensitive languages, but from what I have experienced such a task does not fall under the  usual parsing solutions. You at least have to step beyond context-free languages.

The way I decided to model this example of layout rules is as a binary tree. Nodes are the line content. Descending to the left represents maintaining the same indent level whereas descending to the right represents increasing the indent level.

```
 root
/   \
ε   fileA
   /     \
  sub1:   ε
  |    \___
  |        |
  fileG     fileB – ε
  |         |     
  sub3:     fileC – ε
  | \       |
  ε  fileH  sub2: —+
            |      |
            fileF  fileD
                   |
                   fileE
```

I have modeled your source file as such a tree. You will also note that in respect to line order the tree descends to the right first, then left second.

What we have now is a way to view the source in a brace-style way which unlike layout-style can be parsed with any language parsing tool. For example, say we want to generate tokens to be consumed by a parser. This can be easily done recursively as your intuition hinted.

1. Emit the token for the root node (if the node is ε then we emit no token).
2. Emit an open brace and then recurse on the right subtree.
3. Emit a close brace and then recurse on the left subtree.

In terms of tree traversals this is close to a right-to-left preorder. However, we are also adding a close brace in-order.

I now follow this algorithm to tokenise the example. For simplicity I just use the names in the original source as the token names and also add `{` and `}` as tokens.

```
(recursion_depth.step_number)
(1.1) root
(1.2) root {
(2.1) root { fileA
(2.2) root { fileA {
(2.3) root { fileA { }
(3.1) root { fileA { } sub1:
(3.2) root { fileA { } sub1: {
(4.1) root { fileA { } sub1: { fileB
etc.
```

Finally arriving at (formatted for clarity)

```
root {
  fileA { }
  sub1: {
    fileB { }
    fileC { }
    sub2: {
      fileD { }
      fileE { }
    }
    fileF { }
  }
  fileG { }
  sub3: {
    fileH { }
  }
}
```

From here I hope it is clearer how you can construct an abstract syntax tree for your language. If you want to construct the tree I mention then consider keeping a stack of indentation levels. It requires a bit of thinking but I'll leave you to that.

Comment: It is just too overkill for a simple tree-like structure to be implemented in Context-Free Grammar. Basically the indentation already represents a scope for a sub-tree beneath it. Do you know Python use indentation to define block?

Comment: Thank you for the in depth response. This actually does help me understand the concept even though it is abstract.

Comment: @Gilang I am not sure what is meant by "overkill" here. I touch on context-free languages only to say that such a layout-style language is not one (I do not have a rigorous proof but am certainly stumped for a grammar). When I say "layout-style" I am referring to the indentation being significant, as for example it is in Python. What I address in my answer is how to get from layout-style (not easy to parse) back to brace-style (easy to parse).

Answer (score 0):

This code works with your posted file:

```
     //The top-level Node
    TreeNode root;

    //Temp value for processing in parseTextIntoTree
    TreeNode ParentNode;

    //Temp value for processing in parseTextIntoTree
    int actualdepth = -1;

    //The depth step between two layers
    int depthdifference = 3;

    public void buildDirectoryFromFile(string file)
    {
        string line;
        StreamReader data = new StreamReader(file);

        int depth = 0;
        while ((line = data.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            depth = line.Length - line.TrimStart(' ').Length;
            parseTextIntoTree(line, depth);
        }

        this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
    }

    public void parseTextIntoTree(string line, int depth)
    {
        //At the beginning define the root node
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new TreeNode(line);
            ParentNode = root;
            actualdepth = depth;
        }
        else
        {
            //Search the parent node for the current depth
            while (depth <= actualdepth)
            {
                //One step down
                ParentNode = ParentNode.Parent;
                actualdepth -= depthdifference;
            }

            ParentNode = ParentNode.Nodes.Add(line.Trim());
            actualdepth = depth;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I tried Gilang's suggestion which was posted just before yours and  it worked. Yours also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Since you specified the depth would be refering to the spaces/indents. Thus

```
TreeStruc = @"root:
               fileA
               sub1:
                  fileB
                  fileC
                  sub2:
                     fileD
                     fileE
                  fileF
               fileG
               sub3:
                  fileH";
TreeStruc = Regex.Replace(TreeStruc, " ", "-");
TreeStruc = Regex.Replace(TreeStruc, "---", "-");
using(StringReader reader = new StringReader(TreeStruc))
{
    string line;
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int cnt = line.Count(f => f == '-');
        String str2Replace = new String('-', cnt);
        line = Regex.Replace(line, str2Replace == "" ? "-" : str2Replace, cnt.ToString() + "~ ");
        updatedTreeStruc = updatedTreeStruc + line + "\n";
    }
}
```

It would show the result as follows:

```
root:
1~ fileA
1~ sub1:
2~ fileB
2~ fileC
2~ sub2:
3~ fileD
3~ fileE
2~ fileF
1~ fileG
1~ sub3:
2~ fileH
```

Now from here on we already know the depth that is the number in front of the string.

In the same way we can analyze whether the string is a folder or a file.

Comment: if you sort by number you can't say where should be `fileH` in _sub3_ or _sub1_

Comment: Yeah sorting was attempted by me and it did not work, @Gilang posted a solution that works, thanks for the reply.